# Slides are not separating and shown in same page like a document in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to learn R markdown. 
So, I opened the default R markdown slide presentation document. Then I change the part to [Slide with R Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApBap.jpg).When I knit the code I created the slides are not separated but are shown like a single [document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfooY.jpg). When I remove the code then the slides are separated like the way I want.

Here is the code:

### Slide with R Output

````
```{r Moisture}
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

Moisture_kurokawa <- read_csv("raw.csv") %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(timestamp = lubridate::mdy_hms(sprintf("%s %s", Date, Time)))

hc <- highchart(type="stock")
for (k in names(Moisture_kurokawa)[3:7]) {
  hc <- hc_add_series_times_values(hc=hc, dates=Moisture_kurokawa$timestamp, 
                               values=pull(Moisture_kurokawa, k), name = k)
}
hc%>%hc_legend(enabled=TRUE)

```
````

I am using slidy presentation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You haven't included any page breaks.  I suggest rather than opening a blank file, open from a template and use one of the slide examples.  are you thinking that you wan each of the models on a separate page? THat's going to be a bit more advanced.

Comment: @Elin Doesnt adding ## automatically make a new slide? If not , how do I add page breaks in my case.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you using RStudio?

Comment: @ScipioneSarlo Yes. https://imgur.com/a/3Yggs. When I remove my code it becomes slide presentation again.

Comment: here:
http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-11.html
you can find how to set slide presentations according to the format in use.

Comment: @ScipioneSarlo Thank you. I have already checked it. It shows two ways to separate slides using ## and ---. I have already tried those but didn't help. I don't understand why putting my code removes the slide feature.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your code because of "raw.csv" file...try to change format (not slidy presentation but ioslides)

Comment: @ScipioneSarlo I have already tried that too. Here you go. The raw file .https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvxyfgm3s284g0h/raw.csv?dl=0

Comment: @MrGoodNews yes but the code in your question does not show any ### at all.

Answer (score 2):

I tested, it seems to work fine now (obviously you have to set the path of your data):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
    ioslides_presentation:
        fig_width: 7
        fig_height: 6
        fig_caption: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## Slide with R Output {.flexbox .vcenter}

```{r message=FALSE}
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

Moisture_kurokawa <- read_csv("./raw.csv") %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(timestamp = mdy_hms(sprintf("%s %s", Date, Time)))

hc <- highchart(type="stock")
for (k in names(Moisture_kurokawa)[3:7]) {
  hc <- hc_add_series_times_values(hc=hc, dates=Moisture_kurokawa$timestamp, 
                               values=pull(Moisture_kurokawa, k), name = k)
}
hc %>% 
    hc_legend(enabled=TRUE)

```
````

Comment: I didn't see you have set `echo=F` in chunk options

Comment: Thank you. I was able to do create different slides in ios_slides but still cannot create same results in Slidy_presentation. Thank you for your time